# Must you define a data type when declaring a variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Must you define a data type when declaring a variable in JavaScript?

Comment: No, you can define variables in javascript like `var myVariable`

Comment: to say "you can" suggests there's another option - there isn't ... variables are untyped

Comment: @jaromandaX Good point, you MUST declare variables with the var keyword, but is now too late to edit my comment

Comment: of course, there's var, let and const now :p and not using any of those is equivalent to window.xxx (in a browser)

Answer (score 0):

No, you ca go with just

var x = 5;

The interpreter would guess what type the var is.

Answer (score 0):

No. Javascript is not strongly typed.

Answer (score 0):

No, in Javascript variables are defined by simply using the `var` keyword followed by your variable name.

Example

```
var intVariable = 3;

var stringVariable = "Dog";
```

You can read more about javascript variables [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_variables.asp)